# Typescript missmatches type when removing key and adding it back to extended Type object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a class that handles multiple types, all of them have something in common (they are lacking an ID before, and they have that ID after).

After I'm removing that particular key from type and add it back to it in a function, typescript complains that it can be unrelated:

`'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "id">>'.(2345)`

I've made a playground example that can be viewed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSzAQSgXigbwFBSgQwC4oBnYAJwQDsBzAGmwF8BubbUSWRMAIXS1xQARsSEB7MXAj4qDFmw7R4SZAHUEwABYBJACL9lKKADIBeBABNiZSrTkLwS7j3Va9B5ybNRL1itXomNgBjOHwSEi4kAAkZCylyAB4AFSgIAA9gCCoLSMM1DR19AB8o3lcigD5vRDJiZIBtAF1%20ZtZBfAsLZLEAGQQyfgAKC3xgIigAeQBbDRS6KAByS0XK5oBKdGqcPDxgsSpBy35FrLJF9t2oUfGAOgAzMXIAUXxgzSGqCAB3Qy3vK5aAa3WrAW5gACuJA%20OyucMsDDhu1uKK%20v24iLhjHWrCu2MEjCCbCAA).

The code looks like this:

```
type ClipA = {
  a: string,
};

type ClipB = {
  b: boolean,
};

type ClipAWithID = ClipA & {
  id: string,
}

type ClipBWithID = ClipB & {
  id: string,
}

class ClipHandler<T extends ClipAWithID | ClipBWithID> {
  list: T[] = [];

  addToList = (data: Omit<T, 'id'>[]) => {
    const id = 'test';

    data.forEach(newClip => {
      this.list.push({
          id,
        ...newClip,
      });
    })
  }
}
```

With the `.push` throwing the error:

[image]

Any idea on what would be the best way to fix this, or is it an issue with how Typescript parses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is saying that it is not sure that `{ id, ...newClip }` is of type `T`. Because `T` could be redefined between it's declaration in `ClipHandler` and it's use in `addToList`.

You can tell typescript about how sure you are that `T` is indeed equals to `T` by using the `as` keyword.

Like : [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSzAQSgXigbwFBSgQwC4oBnYAJwQDsBzAbmwF8HtRJZEwAhdLXKAEbEBAexFwI+Kg2bZW4aPCTIA6gmAALAJIARXkpRQAZHzwIAJsTKVaMlm0Wcuazbv1PjpqBasVq9JhYAYzh8EhIOJAAJKXMJcgAeABUoCAAPYAgqcwiDVXVtPQAfSO4XQoA+LzByEUygzPMoRDJiJIBtAF1eLpY8MABXAUQggnNzJJEAGQQyAApzfGAiKAB5AFt1ZIAaKAByCz2KroBKYgA3EQsvPCCRKjJvJow9zLI9vrwoReWAOgAzETkACi+CCGjmVAgAHcDOgqjgvl9NLNfi1gL9BiQIYikXiLNt+HioL9SVDYZxCcTGAQIkkTgwkYwTvxGEw5NggA)

```
type ClipA = {
  a: string;
};

type ClipB = {
  b: boolean;
};

type ClipAWithID = ClipA & {
  id: string;
};

type ClipBWithID = ClipB & {
  id: string;
};

class ClipHandler<T extends ClipAWithID | ClipBWithID> {
  protected list: T[] = [];

  public addToList(data: Omit<T, 'id'>[]): void {
    const id = 'test';

    data.forEach(newClip => {
      this.list.push({
          id,
        ...newClip,
      } as T);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done for now, thanks! I was also curious if I'm doing something wrong on declaring the types or there's a smarter way to declare them to let typescript figure it out that those are indeed the same.

Comment: Unfortunately none that I know of. After digging into the issue, it seems that the responsible of this error is the `Exclude` type used by `Omit` which makes TypeScript incapable of matching the two types. [see](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35858#issuecomment-573909154)